# View onDraw(Canvas c) versus draw(Canvas c) in android?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I am new to android development, I am exploring about `View`. I come across to known two methods `onDraw(Canvas c)` and `draw(Canvas c)`.

Could please explain me the difference and usage of these two methods? Which method will give better performance(FPS) when updating canvas with images?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is difference between them

1. The **[onDraw(Canvas c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)** is a override method and automatically called when the view is being rendered. Here you can do your additional drawing like make circles, lines or whatever you want.
2. The **[draw(Canvas c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)** is used to manually render this view (and all of its children) to the given canvas. The view must have already done a full layout before this function is called. When implementing a view, implement `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` instead of overriding this method. If you do need to override this method, call the superclass version.

Or in simple words **draw(Canvas c)** is simply a function of a view that you can call after the view is rendered for the first time. This function can be used for custom drawing on any view. You need to provide the canvas on which this view will rendered and also you have to do all the drawing on the canvas before calling this function.

Comment: Could please tell me the  performance(FPS) between these 2 methods

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Seems like you just pasted from the inline documentation

Comment: From my test, both will be called when the view is rendered. draw(Canvas c) will be called first, and then onDraw(Canvas c) called inside draw(Canvas c). So i don't think that the word "not automatically called" here is valid since both is "automatically called" when the view is rendered.

Comment: draw is automatically called by framework.

measurement is done with onMeasure() callback and calling setMeasuredDimensions within it.

Not related to draw/onDraw directly.

draw() calls onCall() and does some extra stuff. This answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: The answer is accepted and highly scored, but sadly the second statement is completely wrong.

Answer (score 16):

Just if someone was still looking for answer like me and didn't find it.

The draw() method is called by the framework when the view need to be re-drawn and the draw() method then calls the onDraw() to draw the view's content.

```
void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
     ..... do default stuff (background, layers)
     onDraw(canvas)
     ..... do other stuff ( scroll bars, fading edges, children)

}
```

Comment: Post a documentation reference please. Good answer.

Comment: I actually checked the source code for that, but you can see that when rendering, the ViewGroup each call its children 'draw()' method, you can check that here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Comment: @KarimTarabishy can we call draw method using invalidate method?

Comment: That's why you should override onDraw(), not draw()

Answer (score 14):

There is a misconception about this as a result of awkward API documentation.
The short answer is that `draw(Canvas)` is an *inbound* call on a View to do some important stuff and somewhere in the middle of the `draw(Canvas)` implementation it will also trigger an `onDraw(Canvas)` callback.

- Don't override `draw(Canvas)` when implementing a custom `View` intended to be used inside a layout.
- If your custom view is intended to be used as a full screen game, then overriding `draw()` will save you some unneeded calls on every cycle.

**Longer Answer**

- The framework uses `draw(Canvas)` in its draw cycle. This is what I could find in the View code:

  - Step 1: draw the background, if needed
  - Step 2: save the canvas' layers
  - Step 3: draw the content --- `onDraw()` comes here
  - Step 4: draw the children
  - Step 5: draw the fade effect and restore layers
  - Step 6: draw the scrollbars

**Useful tip**

- You can render any view into an offscreen Bitmap you create, and later use this bitmap anywhere:

  ```
  Canvas c = new Canvas();
  c.setBitmap(myOffscreenBitmap);
  myView.draw(c);
  ```

  - for simple cases (when it's not a ViewGroup and no scrollbars are needed), the simple `onDraw(Canvas)` could also do the trick.

Comment: This answer is pretty accurate, but there is a reason to over-ride draw instead of onDraw(c), and not call super.draw(c).

Performance

If you don't care about framework features and want to draw as fast as possible, e.g. a game like situation in a View, you might want to skip that stuff.

Comment: @HaMMeReD agree, it makes sense to skip the framework code in a game loop. But if implementing a custom view inside a view hierarchy, the framework code is required.

Comment: In case of ViewGroup, I found to use draw instead onDraw. Because onDraw called before drawing children, so at initial state of onDraw I don't know anything about child views, for example measurements

Comment: @AkbolatSSS both are called during the same method in a synchronous manner, draw() comes first, and then onDraw(). So there is no difference in regard to children measurements. Both happens after the layout is completed and sizes are set to everything.

Comment: @AmirUval disagree, I checked that behavior, the ViewGroup doesn't know anything about children sizes in onDraw, it will get this info after `Step 4` or more correctly after `dispatchDraw(canvas)` completes