# What is difference between draw() and onDraw() method in View class?

Tags: android

What is difference between `draw()` and `onDraw()` method in `View` class?

Comment: There is a well explained answer to this here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640541/view-ondrawcanvas-c-versus-drawcanvas-c-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640541/view-ondrawcanvas-c-versus-drawcanvas-c-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceView.draw() basically calls View.draw(); If you want to implement your drawing, you should do it in View.onDraw() which is for you to implement which even says in the source code comments.

This method is called by ViewGroup.drawChild() to have each child view draw itself. This draw() method is an implementation detail and is not intended to be overridden or to be called from anywhere else other than ViewGroup.drawChild().
As for difference between them:
draw():

```
/*
* Draw traversal performs several drawing steps which must be executed
* in the appropriate order:
*
*      1. Draw the background
*      2. If necessary, save the canvas' layers to prepare for fading
*      3. Draw view's content
*      4. Draw children
*      5. If necessary, draw the fading edges and restore layers
*      6. Draw decorations (scrollbars for instance)
*/
```

onDraw() is empty. Its for you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the methods is:

1. The **onDraw(Canvas c)** method is a override method and is automatically called when a view is being rendered. You can add additional functionalities here, like making circles or drawing lines. I.e. whatever you want.
2. The **draw(Canvas c)** is used in order to manually render this view and all of it's children, to the given canvas 'c'. The view must have already done a full layout before this function is to becalled. When implementing a view, implement onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) instead of overriding this method.

This simply means that, **draw(Canvas c)** is a function that is **Not** automatically called when a given view is being rendered. The user is needed to provide the Canvas 'c', on which the view will be rendered. The user also have to do all the drawing on the canvas before calling this function.

Comment: you just copied the answer from the question "View onDraw(Canvas c) versus draw(Canvas c) in Android"!!